# Using a SafeUrl in a background image CSS expression with ngStyle?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

Trying to set a background image using `SafeUrl` like this.

```
<h1>Image Test</h1>
<img [src]="imageURL" width="500px" height="500px">

<br>

<code>{{imageURL}}</code>

<div id="i" 
     class=".background-image"
     [ngStyle]="{'background-image': imageURL}">
></div>
```

The `img` tag renders, but the `div` does not.

Any ideas?

This is the Stackblitz demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-to-safe-url?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

The image is loaded like this:

```
this.loadImage().subscribe(i=>
{
     this.image = i
      this.imageURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(this.image))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background-image property syntax for URLs is url("[URL]")

html

```
   <div id="i" 
         class=".background-image"
         [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getBackgroundImageUrl(imageURL)}">
    ></div>
```

ts

```
getBackgroundImageUrl(url) {
     return `url("${url.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity}")`;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but now love: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-to-safe-url-fork?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Interesting string ... `changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity` ...

Comment: I am glad I helped :D
If it works, you can accept and upvote the answer :D

Comment: It was funny to me when I saw `changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity` for the first time also :D

Comment: Yeah :) - I gave your other answers some love too - so you should see a point boost - Thanks again - I'm so happy this works!!